# Can I map keys like 'nj' that move the cursor down n line in vim/nvim

Tags: vim

I want to map <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to adjust the window size in NeoVim.
I want this mapping to shadow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd><</kbd>.

This is what I have:

```
nnoremap <Tab>, <C-w><
```

But, I can't use a count with my mapping like I would with `<C-w>[count]<`. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd><</kbd> will adjust the window size by 5 characters.

How can I use a count with my mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[count]<Tab>,` instead. In the unmapped version, `<C-w>[count]<` works because the count is acting on `<`. This won't work for your mapping however, where Vim is expecting the keypresses <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I entered a`[count]` before my mapping and it works well.